# Broadcast channel api not triggering, workbox

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I am new with workbox and have been trying to integrate it with my react app. Caching works fine but seems like broadcastUpdate is not triggering when content of file is changed.

This is the code snipped in the service worker:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(/\.(?:css)$/,
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'css-cache',
    broadcastUpdate: {
      channelName: 'api-updates'
    },
    plugins: [
      new workbox.broadcastUpdate.Plugin(
        'api-updates'
      )
    ]
  })
);
```

And I am listening for it in my main file(index.js).Code snippet there is

```
const updatesChannel = new BroadcastChannel('api-updates');
updatesChannel.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Received', e.data);
  alert('updated');
};
```

When the content of css file changes then no message is received in updatesChannel.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this as well, and same results for me.. it turned out that the headers were not readable by the client. This is a CORS thing. What solved it for me was to explicitly add these headers (or the ones you use) in the Django settings:

```
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ['Allow', 'Content-Length', 'ETag', 'Last-Modified', ]
```